# Remove pushpin on Bing Maps API using Python requests

Tags: python, bing-maps

```
imagerySet = "Aerial"
address = session['address']
zoomLevel = ZOOM

url = f"https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Imagery/Map/{imagerySet}/{address}/{zoomLevel}"

params = {
    'mapSize': "512,512",
    'format': "png",
    'mapMetadata': "false",
    'key': os.environ.get('BING_MAPS_API'),
    'zoomLevel': zoomLevel,
    'dcl': "1",
}

response = requests.get(url, params=params)
image = open_image(response)
```

using the `dcl` param, I can control "decluttering" the pins.  But I need the pin gone because I'm using this for a real time computer vision application, and the pin is confusing the model.

Is there a parameter I can pass to get rid of the pushpin using this format?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you change the pin to transparent? like putting a transparent pin image this way it will be invisible

Answer (score 1):

The pin is being added because you specified an address. There are two ways to achieve what you are looking for:

1. Geocode the address first, then use the coordinates or bounding box to retrieve an image (`center` or `mapArea` parameters).
2. For machine learning purposes, you may find using map tiles directly a more efficient method. This is how many map companies have been doing their AI (e.g. Bing Building extracts). For example: https://shuggiefisher.github.io/machine-learning-with-openstreetmap-tiles.md/

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the correct API for getting a map without a pin - the one you have above is specifically to get a map with a pin for a searched location. The API you want is this one:
[https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Imagery/Map/imagerySet?mapArea={mapArea}&mapSize={mapSize}](https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Imagery/Map/imagerySet?mapArea=%7BmapArea%7D&mapSize=%7BmapSize%7D)
See documentation here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/rest-services/imagery/get-a-static-map
If all you have is an address as input, you can turn that into a lat/long with the geocoding service.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/rest-services/locations/
By the way, you may want to check the terms of use to make sure what you're doing is allowed. Building a derivative product or training ML applications is not normally part of the imagery license.